# Convert Query to Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can I write the lambda expression for the following piece of SQL query:

```
Sales_This_Month = SUM(CASE 
                         WHEN Trxn_Type_Code IN ('S','PS','RTN','GS','GR') 
                              AND YEAR(Trxn_Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                           THEN Amount 
                           ELSE 0 
                       END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following  Lambda Expression on your datasource object. Here `salesData` is your datasource object. For know more about where [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
 var result = salesData.Where(x=> (IList<string>)new [] { "S","PS","RTN","GS","GR" }).Contains(x.Trxn_Type) &&  Trxn_Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Sum(x=>x.Amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following:

```
var result = salesData.Select(d => d.Where(x=> (IList<string>)new [] { "S","PS","RTN","GS","GR" })
.Contains(x.Trxn_Type) &&  Trxn_Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)).Count!=0?
d.Where(x=> (IList<string>)new [] { "S","PS","RTN","GS","GR" })
.Contains(x.Trxn_Type) &&  Trxn_Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Sum(x=>x.Amount) : 0);
```